# Using a custom ACF image size in a while loop

Tags: wordpress, advanced-custom-fields

I am trying to display an image in a while loop that uses a custom image size set-up in the functions.php file.

The code below is:

```
    <?php
    elseif(get_row_layout() == 'services_list'):

    $image = get_sub_field('image');

    // Image variables
    $url = $image['url'];

    // Thumbnail size attributes
    $size = 'services-image';
    $thumb = $image['sizes'][$size];
    $width = $image['sizes'][$size . '-width'];
    $height = $image['sizes'][$size . '-height'];
?>
<section class="content">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="columns medium-12">
            <ul class="medium-block-grid-4" data-equalizer data-options="equalize_on_stack: true">
                <?php
                    if(have_rows('services_list')):
                        $count = 0;

                        while (have_rows('services_list')) : the_row();
                            $count++;
                ?>
                            <li>
                                <a href="<?php echo get_sub_field('link'); ?>">
                                    <img src="<?php echo get_sub_field('image'); ?>" />

                                    <div class="service_title">
                                        <p><?php echo get_sub_field('text'); ?></p>
                                    </div>
                                </a>
                            </li>
                <?php
                        endwhile;
                    endif;
                ?>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
</section>

<?php endif; ?>
```

However, the image path returns 'Array' in the code?

Comment: HI there.  Please do `print_r($image)` and report what is shown.

Answer (score 0):

Change in your custom field **return format** in **Image array** to **Image URL**.

[image]